# multiple tables for Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend Framework 2. I successfully completed the Album tutorial for ZF2. Now I'd like to display only a certain data from multiple tables in the database. I have a simple database setup with tables, for example, person, books, status..etc. It's really not important what the database's supposed to do. What I would like to know is if there's a tutorial that would show me step-by-step guidance to display data from table joins. I have seen snippets of codes showing how to do joins, but I haven't found any tutorials on setting up the classes, and how to configure Module.php. In other words, the Module in Album has one table name hardcoded in getServiceConfig(). But how do I set it up so it knows I'm requesting data from multiple tables. Also, if I want to setup the relationship, do I still create class for database tables like in Album tutorial, or is it going to be something different. Can you please help, or show me the right path? If you know of any tutorial that explains handling multiple tables, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ablums tutorial uses `Zend\Db\TableGateway` which does not support joining to multiple tables.

You need to use `Zend\Db` directly or via a mapper class, such as `AbstractDbMapper` within the ZfcBase module.

The basic usage looks like this:

```
<?php

// Given that $dbAdapter is an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

use Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();

$select = new Select();
$select->from('album')
   ->columns(array('album.*', 'a_name' => 'artist.name'))
   ->join('artist', 'album.artist_id' = 'artist.id');

$statement = $dbAdapter->createStatement();
$select->prepareStatement($dbAdapter, $statement);
$driverResult = $statment->execute();

$resultset = new ResultSet();
$resultset->initialize($driverResult); // can use setDataSource() for older ZF2 versions.

foreach ($resultset as $row) {
        // $row is an ArrayObject
}
```

The `join()` method is used to perform the join between the `album` and `artist` table. We also use `columns()` to select which columns are returned. In this case, I create an alias called `a_name` for the `name` column within the artist table.

Once the `Select` object is set up, then the rest is the standard `Db` code that will return a `ResultSet` object for you containing the data.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll give it a shot. Meanwhile, do you know of any working tutorials that uses Zend\Db. Since I'm new to Zend, it's gonna take me a while to fully understand. It'll be extremely helpful if I can see the tutorial where they have used Zend\Db to retrieve data and display them. Nonetheless, thank you for your help.

Comment: Rob, couple things still not clear to me. Do I create classes for each tables I have? What do I do in Module.php. I currently have public function getServiceConfig() in Module as shown in Album tutorial. I do understand what you showed above, but my current problem is that I don't know how to begin talking to the database. A tutorial would be extremely helpful. Thanks

Comment: I create classes for each logical entity - which usually maps to a row in a table, but not always (sometimes the mapper always joins).  I'll try and sort out some code on Github.

Comment: In later versions of ZF2 there is no such method as setDataSource(), instead use initialize().
So, above code would read:
$resultset->initialize($driverResult);

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on Robs excellent answer, its simple to take it a step further and populate multiple objects to form the relationship you require.

```
<?php

// Given that $dbAdapter is an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

use Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();

$select = new Select();
$select->from('album')
   ->columns(array('album.*', 'artist.*'))
   ->join('artist', 'album.artist_id' = 'artist.artist_id');

$statement = $dbAdapter->createStatement();
$select->prepareStatement($dbAdapter, $statement);
$driverResult = $statement->execute(); // execute statement to get result

$resultset = new ResultSet();
$resultset->setDataSource($driverResult);

$albumHydrator = new AlbumHydrator;
$artistHydrator = new ArtistHydrator;

foreach($resultset as $row) { // $row is an ArrayObject
    $album = $albumHydrator->hydrate($row);
    $artist = $artistHydrator->hydrate($row);
    $album->setArtist($artist);
}
```

You should also look at hydrating result sets to build your objects for you directly from the ResultSet:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html

Answer (score 0):

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
$select = new Select();
// or, to produce a $select bound to a specific table
// $select = new Select('foo');

$select->join(
     'foo' // table name,
     'id = bar.id', // expression to join on (will be quoted by platform object before insertion),
     array('bar', 'baz'), // (optional) list of columns, same requiremetns as columns() above
     $select::JOIN_OUTER // (optional), one of inner, outer, left, right also represtned by constants in the API
);

$select->from(array('f' => 'foo'))  // base table
    ->join(array('b' => 'bar'),     // join table with alias
    'f.foo_id = b.foo_id');         // join expression
```