# Zend (ZF2) classes with foreign key

Tags: zend-framework2

I am searching how to solve my problem, but i am having some problems solving it. I am beginner in Zend, and i know this issue isn't hard to solve, but if someone can give me some light.

I have 2 simple tables:

LOCATION

1. loc_id
2. loc_name
3. loc_bld_fk  <- Foreign Key

BUILDING

1. bld_id
2. bld_name

How do i reference the building in the location class? I keep finding different methods, some of them are for the ZF1, so what is the simplest way to do it in ZF2? If someone can help me, i would appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend Db module then there is a good example of how to do this in this question [multiple tables for Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946165/multiple-tables-for-zend-framework-2)

I would highly recommend you use an ORM such as propel or doctrine 2. As it will give you much more flexability and take care of these relationships for you with very little effort.

Here is a link to the doctrine 2 module for zend 2

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule

If you post some of your model and table gateway code I could provide a working example but without that cannot be of much more help