# Create a subquery using ALL and ANY statements

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, any

I'm trying to make this query

```
SELECT * FROM district 
WHERE id = ANY (SELECT districtId FROM address 
WHERE id = ANY (SELECT addressId FROM schedule
WHERE workshopId = '1'))
```

My real problem is inserting the `ANY` statement.
Does anyone know how to apply `ANY` or `ALL` to the query in Zend Framework 2?

Comment: You don't need to include `ZF2` in your question's title. Please see [What are tags, and how do I use them](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Your question could be titled as "Create a subquery using ALL and ANY statements". I would edit it, but there is an edit in the queue preventing me from doing so.

Comment: but what if I want to have the answer for ZendFramework2 ?

Comment: You have your question tagged with `ZendFramework2`. That will let those answering it know what you need. You also mention `ZendFramework2` in your question body. You don't need to have it in your title. That is what tags are for.

Comment: Oh thnks its much easy to read the question you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use join tables?

```
select * from distrinct as d
join address as a using(districtId)
join schedule as s on s.addressId=a.addressId and s.workshopId = '1';
```

regards

Comment: thnks I think you are right. I'll search how to make join sentences in ZF2. Thnks

Comment: @JorgeAdriánRodriguez take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952663/1815321). It might help you figure out how to do the joins.